# Config Client is not working in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

**Config Client is not working in Spring boot**

I was trying out config server client in Spring boot and came across this weird issue.

I have been able to successfully spin up the config server up and running but while trying to start the config client/consumer, it seems like the client isn't fetching any information from the config server.

**Output while running client:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2020-12-24 02:01:28.717  INFO 3000 --- [           main] c.r.service.profile.ProfileApplication   : Starting ProfileApplication using Java 1.8.0_121 on DESKTOP-RID7KR with PID 3000 (E:\Spring\rent-a-car\profile\target\classes started by Dawg in E:\Spring\rent-a-car\profile)
2020-12-24 02:01:28.727  INFO 3000 --- [           main] c.r.service.profile.ProfileApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-24 02:01:30.161  INFO 3000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-24 02:01:30.263  INFO 3000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 82 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-24 02:01:30.642  INFO 3000 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=99ce795d-c5e8-3f6e-87d9-3efbe096b86a
2020-12-24 02:01:32.012  INFO 3000 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-24 02:01:32.027  INFO 3000 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-24 02:01:32.027  INFO 3000 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2020-12-24 02:01:32.287  INFO 3000 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-24 02:01:32.287  INFO 3000 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3430 ms
2020-12-24 02:01:32.431  WARN 3000 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-12-24 02:01:32.444  INFO 3000 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-24 02:01:32.478  INFO 3000 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-24 02:01:32.513 ERROR 3000 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**bootstrap.yml** (config-client)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: profile
  profiles:
    active: prod
  cloud:
    config:
      name: profile
      uri: http://localhost:8181
```

Have not included any **application.yml** file for config-client.

My config server is up on port 8181 and i am able to fetch the config from github successfully,

Sample success response:

```
{
   "name":"profile",
   "profiles":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":"24275f56bf516d847f171c9fc419ddef141bd39b",
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"https://github.com/vishu221b/rentaca-config-store.git/file:C:\\Users\\Vishal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-2331899650646506\\service-config\\profile-service\\profile-prod.yml",
         "source":{
            "server.port":8081
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"https://github.com/vishu221b/rentaca-config-store.git/file:C:\\Users\\Vishal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-2331899650646506\\application.yml",
         "source":{
            "spring.datasource.url":"jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/rent-a-car?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",
            "spring.datasource.username":"cofix",
            "spring.datasource.password":"C0fiX",
            "spring.datasource.driver-class-name":"org.postgresql.Driver",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy":"org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect":"org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I know there must be some key/value errors in the files above, i'll manage that but only given that my config-client starts fetching config from my config-server running successfully.
There is no security in my config-server so i won't need username, password.

**pom.xml** (config-client)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.reantacar.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>profile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>profile</name>
    <description>Profile service for Rent A Car application.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        &lt;!&ndash;The jar needs to be imported to make the bootstrap.yml configuration file take effect &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rentacar.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**PS:** I have tried debugging this a lot over other stackoverflow questions and official docs on internet, but nothing seems to be fixing my issue. Initially i thought that my bootstrap.yml file must not be loading for some reasons, but now i am feeling that the config isn't working for my client at all because in the startup log it is mentioned that configuration from specific config-server-name/link:port was being tried to be fetched.
Also, please ignore the errors in my grammar :)

Comment: Have you done any progress on it? I'm suffering the same issue...

Comment: The answer posted by @Piotr below is the correct one. This was exactly the issue i was facing in my case and importing the spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap resolved my issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2020.0.0 Spring Cloud Config does not support bootstrap file.

> For a workaround use bootstrap.{yml|properties} and add a dependency on
> spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap to restore the old behavior.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

More information:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the thing i needed. Thanks a lot for your help :))

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem in Spring Cloud Config

If you are using a 2.4.0 or greater version of **spring boot** and
If you are using the 2020.0.0 or greater version of **spring-cloud**.

you need to add this dependency to the **pom.xml** (spring-cloud-config-client)

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Example of my **pom.xml** (spring-cloud-config-client)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pay-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pay-service</name>
    <description>Pay project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Try like this, I hope it will work

Sometimes, it happen because you added the **'config client of spring cloud config'** dependency, it required configuration in **application.properties**, add the configuration of your config server so you see the example below

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=8100
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

However, this was working before, but now and as mentioned above you have to your client project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

spring-boot ver=2.4.3

spring-cloud ver=2020.0.1

Also, you can set the below property in your bootstrap. properties to make the client project fails to startup if fails to connect to the config server:

```
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```